# PostgreSQL query select all but these

Tags: sql, postgresql

table **A**

```
reference, row, count, etc...
```

table **B**

```
reference, row, xxx, etc...
```

how can  I get from table **B** all records with *reference* that are in **A**, excluding those rows with *row* that are in **B**?

```
select "reference", "row", "count", "xxx" 
from B 
where A.reference = B.reference and A.row != B.row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT "reference", 
       "row", 
       "count", 
       "xxx" 
FROM   a 
       LEFT JOIN b 
              ON a.reference = b.reference 
                 AND a.row = b.row 
WHERE  b.row IS NULL
```

Although you want records from table B, which are not in table B. If I read your request.
I believe you want all records from table A, which have a missing reference to table B on row column

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
select b."reference", b."row", a."count", b."xxx" 
from b 
join a on a."reference" = b."reference" 
where a."row" not in (select "row" from b)
```

This would select all rows from B that have a matching "reference" in `A`, but where the A."row" is not present in the "row" values in `B`.